# Error al comprimir una imagen antes de subirla al servidor

Tags: php, android-studio, android-volley

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación que le permita al usuario tomar una foto o seleccionar una de su galería para posteriormente enviarla al servidor en una carpeta que ya esta creada, el problema es que cuando tomo la foto me abre la instancia a la cámara de manera correcta, también me deja tomar la foto sin problemas y la muestra en un **ImageView** pero cuando la quiero enviar al servidor me aparece el siguiente error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat,
>   int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference

Este problema solamente sucede cuando tomo la foto, si el usuario escoge la foto de su galería la imagen se sube sin ningún problema, no se porque me da este error, ademas de que si el usuario elige primero una foto de la galería y la sube al servidor al momento de que el usuario quiera tomar una foto se sube la misma foto que subió desde su galería tampoco entiendo este error ya que en el **ImageView** se muestran las imágenes seleccionadas o fotografía tomada.

Este es mi método onCreate(), en este método pido los permisos para leer la memoria y el acceso a la cámara, también aquí uso los botones para realizar las funciones de tomar fotografía o seleccionar imagen:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
            int leer = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int leer2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            int leer3 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            if(leer == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED && leer2 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED && leer3 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISOS, 1);
            }
        }

        nombreUsuario = findViewById(R.id.nombre);
        profesionUsuario = findViewById(R.id.profesion);
        imagenUsuario = findViewById(R.id.imagen);

        Button enviarUsuario = findViewById(R.id.cargarF);
        Button seleccionarFoto = findViewById(R.id.subirF);
        final Button tomarFoto = findViewById(R.id.tomarF);

        enviarUsuario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                enviarContenido(nombreUsuario.getText().toString(), profesionUsuario.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        seleccionarFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });

        tomarFoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sacarFoto();
            }
        });

    }
```

Este es el método donde tengo el error que solamente sucede cuando tomo la fotografia:

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imagenBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodeImagen = Base64.encodeToString(imagenBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return encodeImagen;
    }
```

Este es el método que uso para subir las fotografías al servidor:

```
public void subirImagen(){
        final ProgressDialog cargando = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Subiendo...","Espere por favor");
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                cargando.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                cargando.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("Volley","Error: "+error.getMessage().toString());
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                String imagen = getStringImage(bitmap);
                String nombreI = nombreUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
                String profesionI = profesionUsuario.getText().toString().trim();

                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                Date date = new Date();
                DateFormat hourFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String subTiempo = hourFormat.format(date).replaceAll(":","");
                Log.i("Tiempo", subTiempo);

                params.put(KEY_NOMBRE, nombreI+subTiempo);
                params.put(KEY_PROFESION, profesionI);
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, imagen);

                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Este es el metodo para abrir mi galeria y escoger una imagen:

```
//Mostramos la seleccion de la imagen
    private void showFileChooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona una imagen"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
```

Mi metodo onActivityResult():

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode ==RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
            Uri filePath = data.getData();

            try{
                //Como obtener el mapa de bits de la galeria
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imagenUsuario.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == 3){
                Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToFile);
                imagenUsuario.setImageBitmap(bit);
            }
            //bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            //imagenUsuario.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

Y por ultimo el metodo donde ejecuto el intent de la camara y el metodo para guardar la foto que tome, que tampoco se guarda en la memoria de mi dispositivo:

```
public void sacarFoto(){
        //Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
        Intent takePic = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if(takePic.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
            File photoFile = null;
            photoFile = createPhotoFile();
            //String pathFile = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();

            if(photoFile != null){
                pathToFile = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePic.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
                startActivityForResult(takePic, 3);
            }
        }
    }

    private File createPhotoFile() {
        String name = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = null;
        try{

            image = File.createTempFile(name, ".jpg", storageDir);
        }catch (IOException e){

            Log.d("Error", "Error: "+e.toString());
        }

        return image;
    }
```